# Can one easily stub methods on all instances of a specific Activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Say I want to make a test for a method that retrieves records. For one of the records I'd like record.remote to be stubbed to return a certain object and for others to return some other object. Class.any_instance comes close to what I want, but I'd like to be able to filter the instances down to those coming from a specific record.

Something like this would be OK if it would work.

```
Answer.any_instance.stub(:remote).and_return do
   if self.id == @answer_2.id
     remote_answer
   else
     remote_complete_answer
   end
end
```

Except that self is not an `Answer` in this case but an `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup`. Can I get to the original object in an and_return block?

Comment: I've currently avoided needing to work on any_instance by stubbing Answer.where that is used to retrieve these Answers and returning Answers with the remote is stubbed properly.

Comment: A better solution is to split up your test into multiple tests. For each variation of record that you have, you are testing a different part of your code. By having multiple tests you can simply use any_instance to stub and not have to worry about different instances of classes with different kinds of stubbing inside a single test.

Comment: But that doesn't help if e.g. you need to verify that a particular one of many different instances of a particular model is the one found/operated upon under certain circumstances.

Comment: In that case I would separate the code that would operate on that object into its own method and then `expect(object).to receive(:particular_method).with(particular_object)`